# Generate specific, non-zero return code?

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on some piece of python code that calls various linux tools (like ssh) for automation purposes. Right now I am looking into "return code" handling.

Thus: I am looking for a simple way to run *some* command that gives me a specific non-zero return code; something like

```
echo "this is a testcommand, that should return with rc=5"
```

for example. But of course, the above comes back with rc=0.

I know that I can call `false`, but this will always return with rc=1. I am looking for something that gives me an rc that I can control.

Edit: first answers suggest to *exit*; but the problem with that: *exit* is a bash function. So, when I try to run that from within a python script, I get "No such file or directory: exit".

So, I am actually looking for some "binary" tool that gives me that (obviously one can write some simple script to get that; I am just looking if there is something similar to *false* that is already shipped with any Linux/Unix).

Comment: How would you be running the command from Python? `subprocess.Popen('exit 5', shell=True` would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `exit` in a subshell.

```
$ (exit 5) ; echo $?
5
```

Comment: That works nicely when I execute it directly within bash. But i need a command that python runs for me (like *false*). Any further thoughts are welcome.

Comment: In that case just invoke a shell in order to have it return the value. `sh -c "exit 5"`

Comment: Give or take some subtleties, in the `cmd_str = "bash -c 'exit 5'"` did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have this function defined in `.bashrc`:

```
return_errorcode () 
{ 
    return $1
}
```

So, I can directly use something like

```
$ return_errorcode 5
$ echo $?
5
```

Compared to `(exit 5); echo $?` option, this mechanism saves you a subshell.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you are asking but custom `rc` can be achieved through exit command.

```
 echo "this is a test command, that should return with " ;exit 5
 echo $?
 5
```